# Do Universal Links provide benefits to a custom UIDocument? (Exported UTI)

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, ios-universal-links, uidocument

I'm creating a new UIDocument and think it would be beneficial for these theoretical use cases:

1. The OS should ensure that my app is the "owner" (no one should claim this type other than external UTI)
2. The end user to be redirected to a webpage or App Store if the app isn't installed.

Do Universal links provide any benefit to custom document types defined within info.plist?